# how do i connect a webRTC content provider to the Janus-Gateway streaming plug-in

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, broadcast, live-streaming, janus-gateway

In the gstreamer - streamingtest example 
(https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/streamingtest.html)
a gstreamer pipe is sending to udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004, which then is broadcasted via webRTC in Janus.
how is it possible to send a webcam-stream from another user through his browser getUserMedia() to Janus-Gateway for broadcasting?
Do i have to configure a pipe for it as well and how would that look like?

I have installed Janus and i am able to run all the Demos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a rtp_forward request possible against the videoroom which would forward the rtp from a publisher in that room to the streaming plug-in or any other ip.
it was added here:
https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/pull/255

instead of rtp_listen though, you should request rtp_forward and also pass in the secret.

(this solution needs a browser, but I marked it as right solution since it works for me this way and also scaling users is possible like this)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to provide a few code snippets in your answer as it will help newbies like me, who are trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: it would look something like this:
{"body":{"request":"rtp_forward","publisher_id":2186766636,"room":1234,"host":"192.168.1.105","audio_port":5000,"video_port":5002,"secret":"adminpwd"}

as far as I understand this would only make sense for scaling the application, since a videoroom with participants as "listeners only" is the same thing as the streaming plug in, so if performance goes down one could forward the stream to another server